# How to enable touch scrolling in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ipad, scrolling, touchscreen, scrollbar

I have a touch screen laptop using Windows 7. I want to browse like in an iPad (drag up/down, not using the scroll bar).

Anyone knows how to browse the web like that?